# A problem occurred evaluating project ':firebase_core'

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, build.gradle

I am trying to run my project but when i run it it give following error

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/Volumes/Volume D/installed-softwares/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.11.0/android/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':firebase_core'.
> Could not find method minCompileSdkgroup() for arguments [io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core] on project ':firebase_core' of type org.gradle.api.Project.


2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script '/Volumes/Volume D/installed-softwares/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 346

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_core'.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_core' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

here is build.gradle(project) file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs "${project(':unityLibrary').projectDir}/libs"
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is build.gradle(app) file

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
    signingConfigs {
       debug {
           storeFile file('/Users/appdev/Desktop/private_key.pepk')
       }
   }

    sourceSets {
       main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.chimp.childrens_wish"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 30
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 30
   buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
    ndkVersion '23.1.7779620'
    dependenciesInfo {
        includeInApk false
        includeInBundle false
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation project(':unityLibrary')
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.1')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    
}
```

and here is my graddle-wrapper.properties file

```
#Tue Jan 18 16:22:29 PKT 2022
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3-all.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

i am using firebase_core 1.4.0 version in pubspec and also firebase messaging 10.0.4 version

kindly give a solution for this.

Comment: Try using the latest versions of these packages on pub.dev and  could you please take a look at your project and confirm if using the latest Gradle version fixes your case?

Comment: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3-all.zip

Comment: its using 7.2 version i have add version in question kindly check and my packages of firebase or new version and still facing this issue

Comment: If your app did build previously but now can't, ensure you use the same Flutter version you have used previously (download from https://docs.flutter.dev/release/archive?tab=windows) and remove the `^` in front of the library versions to not load all the latest libraries. For instance: `cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5` becomes `cupertino_icons: 1.0.5`. Yes of course it is recommended to upgrade to the latest versions, but personally for me upgrading is just not an option for now so this will do.